# Why are braces not mandatory (as shown below)?

Tags: java, syntax

Now everyone speaks that if you wanna use multiple statements inside a control statement, it is mandatory to include them inside braces. However if you use like this:

```
if(condition) //first if statement
if(condition) //if statement nested inside the first
System.out.println("test"); //statement inside the second if statement
```

The code should result an error as the second if statement (without the semicolon) is inside the first one without the braces which completes the first if statement's limit. And hence the scope of the println statement should be out of the first if statement. Therefore the above code should be equivalent to

```
if(condition) {
    if(condition) 
}
System.out.println("test");
```

But it's not like that. The first code runs successfully. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You began your question with this statement:

> Now everyone speaks that if you wanna use multiple statements inside a control statement, it is mandatory to include them inside braces.

That’s absolutely true. The nuance you’re encountering here is what it means for something to be a single statement as opposed to multiple statements.

As @rici noted, in most programming languages an if statement consists of both some sort of conditional expression and a guarded statement to execute if that condition is true. In that sense, an if statement has to have some statement inside of it to be syntactically correct.

So let’s look at your statement, but do it bottom-up. The statement

```
System.out.println("Test");
```

is treated as a single statement. Similarly,

```
if (condition)
System.out.println("Test");
```

is also a single conditional statement. However,

```
if (condition)
```

on its own is not a valid conditional statement; this would be a syntax error.

This means that

```
if (condition1)
if (condition2)
System.out.println("Test");
```

is a single conditional. Specifically, it’s a conditional whose condition is `condition1`. The statement is guards is also a conditional. That conditional has condition `condition2` and guards the print statement.

Comment: So this means that although `if (condition)` is a statement, it is 'not a valid statement'?

Comment: @user12208242 Of course it's a valid statement. That's what your question is about: *why* is it valid. And the asnwer is what @rici told you: the print statement is part of the immediately prior `if` statement, not part of the first one.

Comment: @user12208242: `if (condition)` is not a statement at all. It is the beginning of a statement. But by itself, it is not a statement.

Comment: @rici consider seeing this https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/how-statements-are-used-in-java/ this states that `if(condition)` is a statement and is one of the example which does not require a semicolon.

Comment: @user12208242 I agree with rici here that `if (condition)` on its own isn’t a statement. The full statement is the `if (conditional)` followed by some statement that’s guarded by that conditional. (The link you shared does indeed say the opposite, but I think that’s an error in the linked page.)

Comment: @user12208242: what that book is saying, somewhat clumsily, is that the semicolon is part of the embedded statement but not part of the syntax of the `if` statement itself. That should be evident if you look at the syntax I mention in my answer, in which there are no semicolons. By contrast, the parentheses around the condition *are* part of the `if` statement and not part of the expression (even though an expression could include parentheses). If the `if` statement's syntax included a semicolon, then `if (condition) { )` would be invalid because it doesn't end with a semicolon.

Comment: But it doesn't say that `if (total > 100)` is an `if` statement. It quite clearly says that a typical `if` statement is `if (total > 100) discountPercent = 10;`.

Answer (score 4):

Because a conditional statement includes the statement it qualifies.

Braces are not part of the syntax of the `if` statement. It's syntax is simply:

```
 "if" "(" <expression> ")" <statement>
```

Or

```
"if" "(" <expression> ")" <statement> "else" <statement>
```

One type of statement is the block statement, whose syntax is:

```
"{" <statement>... "}"
```

Where `<statement>...` means "zero or more `<statement>`s".

The block statement can include an if-statement (or any other kind of statement). But it can't chop a statement in half. And `if (condition)` is only half of a statement.